# Reduce array size in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

Suppose, I want to reduce an array size (count of cells). Array had been created by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If I try to select part of array and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, Excel prints an error message

> "You cannot change part of an array."

It does not allow me to change the array size, because I had ***not selected the whole array***.

So, I have to **select all the array, remove it, select the reduced cell range** and **enter the formula again** (I save the formula into clipboard before this).

Is there any method without the array removal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Select the array, for example A1 to A10, click in the formula bar and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now each cell will contain the formula as a regular formula. Select the smaller range, for example A2 to A9, click in the formula bar and then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now the smaller range has the array formula and you can remove the non array entered formulas from cells A1 and A10.

Comment: Very valuable tip!